# Why I am not getting data in my database?

Tags: php

I am trying to POST my data in my database but unable to do... Which mistake I did here? I have simply try to print Query but it prints without any value....
If I did any mistake then let me know..
And suggest me what can I do now...

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "sms";
    
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
        if(!$conn){
            die("Could not connect to the database due to the following error --> ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    
        //echo "success";
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mobno = $_POST['mobno'];
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    
    
        $sql1="INSERT INTO `register`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `mobno`, `dob`) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$mobno','$dob')";
    
        echo $sql1;
    
        if($conn->query($sql1) == true){
            // echo "Successfully inserted";
    
            // Flag for successful insertion
            $insert = true;
        }
        else{
            echo "ERROR: $sql1 <br> $conn->error";
        }
        
        
    
        // Close the database connection
        $conn->close();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What Error does it echo?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input. It's not just about security. If the values you inject contains specific characters (like a single quote), your query will break.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST);` and check what you're actually getting. Add the output to your question. It would also help us if we knew where the data came from. How did you do the post? Form? Ajax? API? Please show us all relevant code (including the form and any relevant js).